# hashlib hash my variables as float instead of str

Tags: python, string, variables, hash, hashlib

At my code i wanna hash variable "liczba" everytime as str, but in my code it count as str only first time. Every next loop it is hashed as float. Also that variable "liczba" should change by adding 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 to it every loop. I try it by using

```
liczba = str(obecna_liczba)
```

but it not working idk why. Any advice?

```
import hashlib

obecna_liczba = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
koncowa_liczba = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
liczba = '0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'


filepath = "X:\hashe.txt"

f = open(filepath, "w")

while(obecna_liczba < koncowa_liczba):
    hash = hashlib.sha256(str(liczba).encode('utf-8'))
    f.write(hash.hexdigest())
    f.write("\n")
    obecna_liczba += 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    print(type(obecna_liczba))
    liczba = str(obecna_liczba)
    print(type(liczba))

f.close()
```

Comment: You can't add such a small number to a floating point number. You'll need a `Decimal` object for that precision.

Comment: So what are you doing here, anyway? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: How i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If what you really need are only the SHA-256 hashes for the strings `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` up until `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010`, you might want to skip the floating point arithmetic and just generate the strings.

The `:046d` format specifier specifies zero-padding of decimal numbers to a width of 46 characters, as per your original numbers.

```
import hashlib

for x in range(1, 11):
    number_string = f"0.{x:046d}"
    print(number_string, hashlib.sha256(number_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

The output is

````
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 164f084fdd4bf692f0d0e8f4505132d7bdffae467377cf2512af321f5c0d9e4c
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 20c3aeba98845b288eb7109b8153c938289c359b8929ee738cde7606960f4399
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 71c0ec3a6a53562682b79f3e8b196637f33a7bed3fc376cf39b6bcd3d78a3e5b
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 2d7e43b48eff27ed8023090160021dffe507ef7bdb8a9e3547e4cf9709df6c79
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005 63037238589c29e32e9468487314acce5d4a093fcfd85df9db5fecc5187fc3e9
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006 e3399f0597f6682b9ff4510b1bc520e4251ef3eda99ab10d25234909d2137744
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007 e168716f1ae7d8df34e0d1394b42b86fab91fb13f1e5b95a4094291980f6d884
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008 2c6379918c12a69aaeb9067be5878a423836e60d20064bcba5ffc3f96cb96ffa
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009 bd96da9bec4c5e4781240d09f7095da2e4c4fba0262bfc48ba635231b0407d4e
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010 4f3201ad75c685abb97b7873cca3092df892630b37bdc8c35bac98ce3ef6e4dc```
````

Comment: If u are still here can u tell how to skip every 35 ? i mean to hash 0,00..001 then 0,00...036?